# ArrayList for Files in Folder Android Internal Storage /storage/emulated/0/

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I want to click a button in my activity and open a separate activity that displays an arraylist of a folder that I want to access. So the code to get to the next activity is simple (start the new activity with an intent). However, I want to display the contents of a folder in this new activity in the arraylist.

The path for this content is in the Internal storage of my device (Not the external/SDcard storage).

I would like to display files from the following directory

/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.../files/

com... is a fake path name, it is just to illustrate that there is a package name.

So bottom line is I want to display the contents in files (text files or pictures, etc.) in the arraylist in my new activity. Whenever I try to point to this path with 'File', it does not show the arraylist, but rather a blank screen.

So for example:

```
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.../files/";
File dir = new File(path);

List values = new ArrayList();

String[] list = dir.list();
if (list != null) {
    for (String file : list) {
        if (!file.startsWith(".")) {
            values.add(file);
        }
    }
}

Collections.sort(values);

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, values);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Is your Arraylist getting populated? With a device that is not Rooted you only have access to very specific directories; therefore your `dir.list()` might return null

Comment: Galvin,

I debugged the program, and yes it is returning null. I am using a non rooted device. This is because not all users will have a rooted device. If the device is not rooted, is there not any way to access the internal storage? 

Or, is there a way to put in minimal or some code to create an on the spot file manager that brings the user to this folder?

Comment: You will only have access to the sdcard and the directory listed here `getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().dataDir`

Comment: Galvin, I actually am able to collect the files in the directory and populate the ListView with each file and its path into the ListView. Now I just need to open the file, read the content, and then display it on the screen; but I am getting an exception thrown when pointing to the file with the openFileInput method. If I find out how to do this I will comment back.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Galvin,

I currently can get the file name and file path, but when I try to use FileInputStream I get an exception thrown. I will send you a response with the code.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is below. I also am having trouble implementing a FileInputStream using the files that I am able to see from the code below. By taking a substring, I can grab the file names but when I use FileInputStream I am having difficulty getting it to read. My exception is thrown on this line of code.

FileInputStream in = openFileInput("test.txt");

My Solution to the actual question.

Inside oncreate

```
lvFiles = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewFiles);

        String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.../files/";

        try {

            List<File> files = getListFiles(new File(path));


            String[] namesOfFiles = new String[files.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
                namesOfFiles[i] = files.get(i).toString();
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.filetextview, namesOfFiles);

            lvFiles.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            //lvFiles.setAdapter(new CustomAdapterArrayAdapter(FilesList.this, files));

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```

End of Inside of onCreate. This is put in onCreate so that the listview is populated immediately once the page is opened.

getListFiles Method start

```
private List<File> getListFiles(File parentDir)
    {
        ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {

            //if (file.getName().endsWith(".txt"))

            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
            } else {
                if(file.getName().endsWith(".txt")){
                    inFiles.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
        return inFiles;
    }
```

getListFiles method End.

Comment: Can you also add the Exception / Stack Trace?